# Do Firebase Rules snapshots affect billing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Do they count as downloads and connections to the database when I use the variables root, data or newData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The Firebase Realtime Database only charges you for the amount of data that is stored, and the bandwidth that is used sending data to various clients and servers. Data that is read in the database rules is not charged.